# How do I use Ansible jinja2 map() and join() filters correctly without template error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jinja2, ansible

From the http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html website it says that I can do the following:

```
  # get a comma-separated list of the mount points (e.g. "/,/mnt/stuff") on a host
  {{ ansible_mounts|map(attribute='mount')|join(',') }}
```

I did this with:

```
    - debug: var="{{ ansible_mounts|map(attribute='mount')|join(', ') }}"
```

This causes the following error for each...

```
 FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected '/'. String: {{/, /homedata, /edbdata, /db1data, /db2data}}"}
```

Am I missing some kind of exception or default statement?

print out of ansible_mounts

```
   root@ip-10-200-241-204:/etc/ansible# ansible -u ubuntu -m setup 10.200.240.10 -a 'filter=ansible_mounts'
 10.200.240.10 | SUCCESS => {
       "ansible_facts": {
           "ansible_mounts": [
        {
            "device": "/dev/xvda1",
            "fstype": "ext4",
            "mount": "/",
            "options": "rw,noatime,data=ordered",
            "size_available": 7024513024,
            "size_total": 8318783488,
            "uuid": "35634654356"
        },
        {
            "device": "/dev/xvdb",
            "fstype": "xfs",
            "mount": "/homedata",
            "options": "rw,noatime,attr2,inode64,noquota",
            "size_available": 13914439680,
            "size_total": 13948157952,
            "uuid": "345634564356"
        },
        {
            "device": "/dev/xvdc",
            "fstype": "xfs",
            "mount": "/edbdata",
            "options": "rw,noatime,attr2,inode64,noquota",
            "size_available": 16061923328,
            "size_total": 16095641600,
            "uuid": "23452345235"
        },
        {
            "device": "/dev/xvdc",
            "fstype": "xfs",
            "mount": "/db1data",
            "options": "rw,noatime,attr2,inode64,noquota",
            "size_available": 16061923328,
            "size_total": 16095641600,
            "uuid": 234523452"
        },
        {
            "device": "/dev/xvdd",
            "fstype": "xfs",
            "mount": "/db2data",
            "options": "rw,noatime,attr2,inode64,noquota",
            "size_available": 16061923328,
            "size_total": 16095641600,
            "uuid": "23423452"
        }
    ]
},
"changed": false
```

}

Comment: Working fine for me. Which ansible version are you using ?

Comment: ansible 2.2.0.0

Comment: Ok. Can you try printing the value of : ansible_mounts ?

Comment: Try removing quotes after var:  - debug: var={{ansible_mounts|map(attribute='mount')|join(',')}}

Comment: Thanks. But same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130551/discussion-between-shasha99-and-cloudish123).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need curly braces in ansible 2.2.0 while using `var`. Try this:

```
- debug: var=ansible_mounts|map(attribute='mount')|join(', ')
```

Note that curly braces are required when using `msg` in ansible 2.2.0. Try this:

```
- debug: msg={{ansible_mounts|map(attribute='mount')|join(', ')}}
```